# how to deny create sqs queue permission to all users if the queue is not encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to "Deny" create sqs queue (`sqs:CreateQueue`) permission for all user if they forgot to encrypt the queue while creating. I tried with the below policy but still the policy is allowing the user to create queue if they are encrypting or not.

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "denysqsifnotencrypted",
      "Action": "sqs:CreateQueue",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "*",
       "Condition": {
           "ForAnyValue:StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:CalledVia": ["kms.amazonaws.com"]
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, you will not be able to do this because SQS does not support any Condition keys. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonsqs.html):

> SQS has no service-specific context keys that can be used in the Condition element of policy statements.

As a workaround, you can create an EventBridge rule that gets triggered anytime an SQS queue is created without a KMS key.

Here's what the EventBridge rule would look like:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.sqs"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["sqs.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateQueue"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "attribute": {
        "KmsMasterKeyId": [""]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then configure an AWS Lambda function as a target for the Eventbridge rule, and you can have this function delete the queue immediately (and you could maybe even notify your users via an email with SES).